# How can I pass a list of strings within a request?

Tags: c#, rest, api, refit

I'm using Refit library for my app and I need to make a call to another service. I need to get all entities with ids that I'm passing.

I tried [Body] attribute and it still doesn't work. I manage to pass a request but the list if ids that another service gets is null while I'm definitely passing existing IEnumerable.

My IRefitProxy:

```
[Get("/students/allByIds")]
Task<IEnumerable<Student>> GetStudentsById(IEnumerable<string> ids);
```

Another service's API:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/students")]
[Route("allByIds")]
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Student> AllByIds(IEnumerable<string> ids)
{
//ids here is null!

//call my repository blablabla
return students;
}
```

I pass an array/List of strings and it comes as null. The path is ok because I manage to fall into the method with breakpoint. How can I manage to pass it correctly?

Comment: What are you using to call the server?  JavaScript?  Razor?

Comment: just usual c# code

Comment: So you use `WebRequest` or `WebResponse` from the server to hit those endpoints?  I was inquiring how the client sends to the server.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I managed to solve this question. Adding `[Query(CollectionFormat.Multi)]` solved the problem.

`[Get("/students/allByIds")]
Task<IEnumerable<Student>>GetStudentsById([Query(CollectionFormat.Multi)]IEnumerable<string> ids);`

The receiving API needs to have `[FromUri]` attribute. Hope it helps someone!

Comment: I don't understand, GetStudentsById is the receiving API or not? Besides that @MalvEarp should work.

Comment: No, it is not. AllByIds() is the receiving API. I tried what @MalvEarp suggested and it didn't work.

Comment: FromUri is now FromQuery I believe in dotnet Core v2

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you are calling your API's endpoint. But have you tried using the FromUri attribute within your method's parameters?

```
[Get("/students/allByIds")]
Task<IEnumerable<Student>> GetStudentsById([FromUri] IEnumerable<string> ids);
```

You should then be able to do call like so:

```
?ids=11&ids=12&ids=13
```

Or even pass an array of strings via JavaScript.

Comment: I call it using Refit library. I have a class with IRefitProxy _proxy field, and I make a call just like this:
`var students =_proxy.GetStudentsById( ids);`

Comment: I tried [FromUri] and now it's super weird. The IEnumerable ids is not null but it doesn't contain any members.